# Install Elasticsearch Service in Linux

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We are developing a java (spring boot) based software which depends on Elasticsearch. Right now we integrate elasticsearch via maven (as artifact).

This version seems to be the same as the .zip / .tar.gz version from the elasticsearch website.

As I have noticed there is a service installer for windows (x86 as well as x64).

But it seems that there is no "service installer" for linux in this package. I can use "./bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid" and the corresponding "kill `cat pid`" command to start/stop elasticsearch but it would be nice to have some form of service installer in this package as well so that elasticsearch is started automatically after an OS reboot.

I know the necessary files for systemd and init.d systems exist (at least in the .deb and .rpm package versions) so I assume it is not such a big deal to have a service installer in the artifact/zip/tar.gz version as well.

Am I right or do I underestimate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If there are the init.d files already, all you need to do is create the shortcut in rc.3 or rc.5 folders. Using redhat distros you'd simply do:

```
$ sudo chkconfig elasticdaemonname on
```

But that's assuming it *is* a daemon. If not, you'll have to daemonize it yourself. There are various possibilities to do this and I'm ready to bet all of them are documented for elasticsearch. But you could look for `daemonize` for start.

Comment: That is not exactly the point. It seems that there is no built in init/system.d config in the artifact/zip/tar.gz package. Sure, I can add the needed files and scripts by myself. But I hoped that there might be a way to avoid that.

Comment: Make your own, it's very easy. See Daemonize